# Content Search Web part to other Site collection

Tags: 2013, web-part, search, site-collection, content

I need to create a **Content Search Web** part restricted to a specific URL. 
I have to show the documents from a list in *an other site collection*.

 Is it possible? 
I'm trying but I do not see results.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the path attribute:

```
path:urlToTheList
```

In the query

Comment: this is my query: path: "http://myRoot/my%20site/my%20list/Forms/AllItems.aspx" but I do not see results :/

Comment: "my list" is a document library

Comment: Well you should not use the /forms/allitems.aspx part, and no encoding

Comment: No luck :/ If I copy the path in the browser, I can see the element. The list is in an other site collection, the problem may be there

Comment: maybe change the content source?